# Is there any way to let HTML background image auto repeat even after height changes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'have a question about HTML's background image styling. As the title says, how could I, if possible, let a div's background image keep on repeat even after div's height changed?

For example, I have this div:

```
#corkboard {
    background-image: url('images-2/corkboard.jpg');
    min-height: 500px;
}
```

The background image `corkboard.jpg` is only a 340 * 340 sized square [that look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9EZW.jpg), when it got imported into `corkboard` div, it automatically repeats and filled up `min-height: 500px` part,
[which the webpage now look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwynl.jpg)

However, when I add child elements to `corkboard`, and the div height automatically extends way longer than `min-height: 500px`, the background image does not keep up repeating and fill up the new height, it just always stays at `min-height: 500px`, the same as how it was initially, [and look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCH0m.jpg)

I know how `cover` works, but that's not what I want to do, because `cover` stretches that one image to cover the whole background, and make the quality bad. I'm seeking for a way to keep the auto repeat updating with the new div size. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Please post your HTML structure. Are you sure the container element with the background-image is the one growing in size?

Comment: You can use the background-repeat property. Since you want to it to repeat on the y-axis, you could use background-repeat: repeat-y;

Comment: @nadz The default value for background-repeat is to repeat in both directions, that's not the issue unless the OP explicitly changed it.

Comment: @skyline3000 You're' right. Then the most likely issue is that the children are overflowing the parent hence the parent.

Comment: OP, if the children inside corkboard is using a float property, make sure you use clear both to make sure the parent gets the height of the children rather than the initial min-height property you've set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the float property on the children, you could do this.

**HTML Structure**

```
<div id="corkboard">
    <div class="corkboard__child">a</div>
    <div class="corkboard__child">b</div>
    <div class="corkboard__child">c</div>
    <div class="corkboard__child">d</div>
    <div class="corkboard__child">e</div>
    <div class="corkboard__child">f</div>
    <div class="corkboard__child">g</div>
    <div class="corkboard__child">h</div>
    <div class="corkboard__child">i</div>
    <div class="clear--both"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#corkboard {
    background-image: url('images-2/corkboard.jpg');
    min-height: 500px;
}

.corkboard__child {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
}

.clear--both {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Although my code is not fixed like this (it uses JS to add a child every time when the user clicks a button), but I still manage to write some JS to add this clear--both class at the end of the div every time, and it works!

Comment: @ZhongqianChen You're welcome. Please mark the question as answered if it is accepted. :)

Answer (score 1):

There's the [background-repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat) property; common values are

Repeat on both x and y axis

```
background-repeat: repeat;
```

Repeat only on the x axis

```
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

Repeat only on the y axis

```
background-repeat: repeat-y;
```

Do not repeat at all

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question - this is just copy and paste from MDN

Comment: Sorry man... I typed it myself but searched for the MDN link.

Besides, the OP asks how to repeat a `background-image` and I dont see how this doesn't answer that.

Comment: @a.mola Thank you! But I had tried this before, it still does not automatically repeat after the div size had changed. That's why I'm posting this question, because common solution didn't seem to work...

Comment: Okay then... My bad @nadz has a good point about the overflowing of the parent